# Accessing android file system programmatically from OS X

Tags: android, macos, filesystems, usb

Is there a way to access the file system of an android device programmatically? Such as a library? It can be in any language.
I'm running OS X and it is a tedious task trying to find a way to backup the phone over USB, therefore I'd like to write my own little tool

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source code of *Android File Manager* for OS X, or, since the device has a file structure,  just access the file structure by returning a file's path inside the file system and do ../ until you're at where you want to be. You can also save the path that you end up with for future use

Comment: You can't "just" access the file structure of android on os x, as there are some incompatabilities unfortunately. Hence my question.

Comment: @BananaCode my bad, let me rethink